# C# Groupby then Sum after Split CSV (no Headers)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

Having read the various post, I think I'm close to getting the result I want but the "sum" part is giving the wrong answer.  I suspect its due to the way I call the "sum" as my csv file does not have column headers.

csv file contains the following:

> 222, 1
>
> 223, 2
>
> 222, 1
>
> 224, 2
>
> 222, -1

What I want to is to:

- read the CSV file and split the data
- group by first column
- sum second column by group

Here is what I have done so far:

```
var newquery = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path_source) //read all lines in csv file
                       let values = line.Split(',') //split the values by separator
                       let price_value = values[0]                                                      
                       group line by price_value into g                           
                       orderby g.Key
                       //select g;
                       select new 
                       {
                           price_column = g.Key,
                           qty_column = g.Sum(x => x[1]) 
                       };

var writesum = newquery.Select(record => record.price_column + "," + record.qty_column);

File.WriteAllLines(path_target, writesum);
```

The path_target file shows:

> 222, 45
>
> 223, 80
>
> 224, 65

This tells me that the `split`, `groupby`, `orderby` syntax is correct but the `sum` is totally wrong.

I suspect one of the reasons the results for the `sum` is wrong is due to the syntax here `qty_column = g.Sum(x => x[1])`.

As my data does not contain headers, I'm not able to call `x.something` as in the examples.

On the other hand I could be totally wrong on this point!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, group the values after they are splitted, not the raw line:

```
group values by price_value into g
```

instead of

```
group line by price_value into g
```

Next parse the `string` you want to sum as `ints` before you sum them:

```
qty_column = g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x[1]))
```

instead of

```
qty_column = g.Sum(x => x[1])
```

since `x[1]` is a `string`.

Now the result is:

```
var newquery = from line in File.ReadAllLines(path_source) //read all lines in csv file.
                       let values = line.Split(',') //split the values by separator
                       let price_value = values[0]
                       group values by price_value into g
                       orderby g.Key
                       //select g;
                       select new
                       {
                           price_column = g.Key,
                           qty_column = g.Sum(x => int.Parse(x[1]))
                       };
```

Which gives you:

> 222, 1
>
> 223, 2
>
> 224, 2

Anyway, fluent syntax will be somewhat more readable:

```
var v = new List<string> File.ReadAllLines(path_source) //read all lines in csv file.
    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
    .Select(x => new { Key = x.First(), Value = x.Last() })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        price_column = x.Key,
        qty_column = x.Sum(y => int.Parse(y.Value))
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help..you saved me many hours of searching!.....novice mistakes on my part I'm afraid!  Learnt something today! Thanks again.