# How to split a string and get sum based on matching values

Tags: c#, .net

Need a bit of help. I generated a string list to help gather some information. I need to split the list back up to add the values based on matching names. My string list are like below (including the middle bar):

- red | 5
- red | 3
- blue | 2
- red | 6
- green | 1

results should be: red = 14 blue = 2 green = 1

My actual code is below:

```
List<string> plist = new List<string>();
ObjectIdCollection mycoll = promptforObjColl("\nSelect Objects: ");
foreach (ObjectId pid in mycoll)
{
    if (pid.GetType() == typeof(Polyline))
    {
        Polyline pcl = pid.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as Polyline;
        plist.Add(pcl.StyleName + "|" + pcl.Area);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Splitting string, grouping them?

Comment: When you are doing plist.Add, why don't you also have a Dictionary<string, int> that you keep a running total with?

Comment: Why are you creating this List<string>? Why aren't you just keeping a List<PolyLine> since that is the primitive data type & you can use it to get strings if you need, like for serialization to file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Groupby then Sum after Split CSV (no Headers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263053/c-sharp-groupby-then-sum-after-split-csv-no-headers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to cross-check your logic of making concatenated string and then iterate through the collection -> split them to get actual values -> process them to group and sum, etc are very costly, I prefer you to use a Dictionary instead like the following:

```
Dictionary<string,double> myDictionaryObj = new Dictionary<string,int>();

ObjectIdCollection mycoll = promptforObjColl("\nSelect Objects: ");
double currentValue;
foreach (ObjectId pid in mycoll)
{
    if (pid.GetType() == typeof(Polyline))
    {
        polyline pcl = pid.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead) as Polyline;
        if(myDictionaryObj.TryGetValue(pcl.StyleName, out currentValue))
        {
            myDictionaryObj[pcl.StyleName]+= pcl.Area;
        }
        else
        {
            myDictionaryObj.Add(pcl.StyleName,pcl.Area);
        }
    }
}
```

Here we are keeping a dictionary to store the values, so that we can check whether particular color exists in that, if yes means add the values or else add the item as a new dictionary entry.

Please note: I assume `pcl.Area` is of type Double and that's why chosen `Dictionary<string,double>`. hope that you won't forget to change the type if needed.

And finally you will get the sum by accessing the key value from the dictionary like the following:

```
double redSum = myDictionaryObj["Red"];
```

Comment: myDictionaryObj[pcl.StyleName]+= currentValue is definitely wrong. It should be myDictionaryObj[pcl.StyleName]+=pcl.Area, or myDictionaryObj[pcl.StyleName] = pcl.Area+currentValue.

Also dictionary entry can be added immediately by assigning, so you can replace myDictionaryObj.Add(pcl.StyleName,pcl.Area) with myDictionaryObj[pcl.StyleName]=pcl.Area;

Comment: @Martheen: Yep you are right, That should be ` myDictionaryObj[pcl.StyleName]+= pcl.Area;` I've updated my post. thanks for the correction

Comment: Also, with your current edit, there's no point of calling currentValue right? Just ContainsKey is enough rather than TryGetValue

Comment: @Martheen: Thanks again! But I think,  `Contains()` needs to traverse the entire collection, since its inside a loops that operation will be expensive, and that's why I've used `TryGetValue` instead for `Contains`

Comment: [ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) is O(1) operation, it doesn't need to traverse because we're dealing with Dictionary

Comment: Also check the [Dictionary](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs) source code, ContainsKey only call FindEntry, while TryGetValue will call FindEntry, then read the value or assign a default value